# Linux fedora how to change to older version of clang

Tags: linux, fedora, terminal, clang

I am currently using Linux fedora and I have the latest version of clang installed 14. I need an older version 12. Is there a way to do this through the terminal.

I have been able to install the current version.

Would I have to install the old library and change the path variables for it?

Answer (score 0):

You can do `# dnf downgrade clang` ('`#`' means escalated privileges, i.e. `sudo`).

**EDIT:** there are several routes one may take here. Depending on your needs, you can

1. Download `clang-12` from [Koji](https://koji.fedoraproject.org/koji/packageinfo?buildStart=50&packageID=21848&buildOrder=-completion_time&tagOrder=name&tagStart=0#buildlist) and then manually downgrade by running `# dnf downgrade /path/to/package.rpm`. *You may want to be careful with this one, since you'll probably have to resolve dependencies manually.*
2. Installing it through `toolbox` (or `distrobox` or similar). This will set up a container for development which makes no changes to the system (except from user-created files, which will *not* be cleaned up if you decide to scrap the container). This method is by far the safest, but everything depends on your needs.

Comment: this just downgrades it to the earliest version of clang 14 and won't go any lower

Comment: @Roberthause Please see my edit.